# Попап-форма с абсолютной позицией игнорирует футер и наезжает на него, хотя не игнорирует шапку

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Всем здравствуйте!

Я бэкендер, поэтому не очень разбираюсь в стилях, но сейчас делаю `full-stack` проект на `Bootstrap-5`.

Мой код вертски:

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-warning sticky-top">
    ...
    </nav>
    <div class="container position-relative form-imitation-popup-parent py-0">
       <div class="card my-5 box-shadow card-form-popup text-center border-dark px-0"
       ...
       </div>
       ...
    </div>
    <footer class="pt-4 px-2 border-top bg-warning mt-auto">
    ...
    </footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.form-imitation-popup-parent {
  min-width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.card-form-popup {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  max-width: 550px;
}
```

Блок всплывающей формы заключен в родителя с атрибутом `position-relative`. Насколько я знаю при таком условии блок с атрибутом `position: absolute` должен игнорировать только блоки, включенные в родительский и это работает по отношению к шапке `navbar`. Но на футер форма наезжает на экранах с маленькой высотой.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить.

Comment: При absolute блок воспринимает только ближайшего родителя с position: relative; а на всё остальное ему пофиг.

Comment: @Евгений Ли понял, спасибо. Выходит, это никак не исправить?

Comment: Если это модальное окно как я понял, зачем вам нужно, что бы footer не закрывался? Он же вроде при Попапе даже затемняет весь задний фон. Или я чего то недопонимаю

Comment: Я что-то наверное не понимаю, но судя по тому, что я вижу, вы самостоятельно пытаетесь создать POPAP? Этот функционал же есть в bootstrpa 5 и он игнорирует при этом и header и footer

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/ - вот в моём понимании модальное окно на bootstrap 5 и для него не нужно стили никакие, они уже есть в bootstrap сборке.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи понял, спасибо, как-то я мимо этого прошел